# How can i make a login form that logs me in into my webmail?

Tags: javascript, php, html, roundcube, directadmin

English is not my native language, so I'm srry if there are some mistakes in this question..

But this is the thing.. I am trying to make a login form on my webpage so I can login to my webmail using my webpage instead of my roundcube.. but when I do that, the webpage is not private so I returns a error..

I am using localhost to login to webmail on a server.. is the problem mabye that it has to be on the same server or is it the code?

```
<div id="content-wrap"><form action="https:www.glazenwasserijnederpel.nl/webmail" method="post"> <input name="login_theme" type="hidden" value="cpanel" />
                            <table class="login" style="width: 200px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody style="text-align: left;">

                                   <strong>Login, alleen voor leden</strong>

                                <tr style="text-align: left;">
                                    <td class="login_lines" style="text-align: left;">Email:</td>
                                    <td class="login_lines" style="text-align: left;"><input id="user" name="user" size="16" type="text" tabindex="1" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="row2" style="text-align: left;">
                                    <td class="login_lines" style="text-align: left;">Password:</td>
                                    <td class="login_lines" style="text-align: left;"><input id="pass" name="pass" size="16" type="password" tabindex="2" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr style="text-align: left;">
                                    <td style="text-align: left;" colspan="2"><input id="login" class="input-button" type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <input name="goto_uri" type="hidden" value="/?login_theme=cpanel" /> </form> <br /> <br />
                        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                            /* Must not include external javascript -jnk 06.20.09 */
                            var init = function() {
                                document.getElementById("user").value = '';
                                document.getElementById("pass").value = '';
                                document.getElementById("user").focus();
                            };
                            if( window.addEventListener ) {
                                window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
                            } else if( document.addEventListener ) {
                                document.addEventListener('load',init,false);
                            }
                            // --></script>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most websites have protection against this sort of form submission, so yes, you have to be on the same server in order to login.

Comment: I have tryed to make it on the same server and i still get the private error.. do you know if it is mabye an option in direct admin or on my email?

Comment: Can you put the exact error you are getting on the question? Maybe if possible, include the login script.

Comment: It is not really a error.. it is more like my browser is giving me the text: this page is private and you have not enough premission.. but I already fixed it with a inlog field that checks if have a email and password en than send you to your webmail.. but it does not log you in..